The maximal ideal of the local ring of the affine variety $X $ at $P$

The ring $K[X]_{\mathcal{m}_p}$ is denoted by $\mathcal{O}_{P,X}$ and called the local ring of the affine variety $X$ at $P$ (K a field).

$$k[X]_{\mathcal{m}_p}=\{\frac{f}{g}|f\in k[X], g\notin\mathcal{m}_P\}/\{equivalence \ of \ fractions\}$$
This local ring has maximal ideal $m_p=A(k[X]_{\mathcal{m}_p})$ where $A=\{f\in K[X]|f(P)=0\}$.
I'm a sophomore and I'm working on a project.
$1:$ I want to know how I can intuitively understand that this is a maximal ideal.
$2:$ How this can be connected to the definition of cotangent space $T_P^{*}{X}:=m_p/{m^{2}_p}$?
I'd like to get some ”informal“ explanation (as simple as possible, or some application in some undergraduate courses so that I can understand and connect them), any help is appreciated!
